# Проверка имени файла

Tags: php

Добрый день! Вот мучаюсь уже не один час в поисках решения (я вроде как нуб, не много:)). Есть код:

```
<?php
     $dir = "../www";   //задаём имя директории
     if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
          $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
          array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
          array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'

             for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '<a href="'.$files[$i].'" title="открыть">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  //выводим все файлы
     }
     else echo $dir.' -такой директории нет;<br>';
?>
```

Данный код создан для того что бы вывести файлы находящиеся в определенной директории (www). Всё бы хорошо, но в директории кроме нормальных файлов, лежат так же и файлы начинающиеся с '~' и '~~', тоесть временные. Список файлов, который скрипт выводит сейчас:

```
array_flip.php;
index.php;
massives.php;
~array_flip.php.htm;
~~Неназванный 3.php.htm;
~Неназванный 3.php.htm;
```

А нужно что бы скрипт просто не выводил файлы с '**~**' и '**~~**', тоесть список файлов должен быть примерно таковым:

```
array_flip.php;
index.php;
massives.php;
```

Вот собственно и суть проблемы. Надеюсь, кто поможет:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такую "заумную мысль" ))

```
$path = "../www";
$d = dir($path);
if ($d) {
    while (false !== ($name = $d->read())) {
        if ($name === '.' || $name === '..') continue;
        $fullPath = $path . "/" . $name;
        if (is_file($fullPath) && $name[0] !== '~') {
            echo '<a href="'.$fullPath.'" title="открыть">'.$name.'</a>;<br>';
        }
    }
    $d->close();
} else {
    echo 'такой директории нет';
}
```

Comment: Сенк! Всё гуд, вери вел!

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предпочел такой вариант, который заодно убирает . и ..

```
function filter($name){
    return !preg_match("/(^~)|(^[.]{1,2}$)/", $name);
};
$result= array_filter($files, "filter");
```

Потому что если потребуется убрать другие файлы из выдачи, то достаточно изменить только регулярное выражение. Например такое уберет файлы bkp.

```
/(^~)|(^[.]{1,2}$)|(\.bkp$)/
```

Comment: Что то типа такого??:
http://pastebin.com/qXt9UCNU

Comment: это лишнее

         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
          array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'

Comment: Уже понял)) Всем огромное спасибо!